# Shared iAd banner bannerViewDidLoadAd not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I am using the following code to setup a shared iAd banner.

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _adView = [[ADBannerView alloc]init];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication ]delegate];
    _adView = [appdelegate adView];
    _adView.delegate = self;
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true;
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

`bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError` is getting called as expected but `bannerViewDidLoadAd` is never called. I am trying to move some buttons up on the screen when the iAd banner loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shared banner does not appear to be just one `ADBannerView`. It looks like you've set multiple `@property`'s for your `ADBannerView` in your `AppDelegate.h` and your `ViewController.h`. Also, `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` is creating an entirely **new and different** `ADBannerView` for you. `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` can be used for a *no hassle* way of implementing iAds in your application. This will create a `ADBannerView` for you and show or hide the `ADBannerView` depending on whether it receives an ad or not from the iAd network. You will want to remove this from your `viewDidLoad` if you plan to implement a `ADBannerView` yourself.

Here is what your implementation of your shared `ADBannerView` should look like:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import iAd;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ADBannerView *iAdView;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _iAdView = [[ADBannerView alloc]init];
    return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController  ()

@end

@implementation ViewController  {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication ]delegate];
    appDelegate.iAdView.delegate = self;
    appDelegate.iAdView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, appDelegate.iAdView.frame.size.width, appDelegate.iAdView.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:appDelegate.iAdView];

    // You created another adView property in your ViewController.h?
    //_adView = [appdelegate adView];
    //_adView.delegate = self;

    // This will actually create ANOTHER ADBannerView
    // Do not use when creating your own ADBannerView
    //self.canDisplayBannerAds = true;
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"iAd LOADED");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    appDelegate.iAdView.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"iAd FAILED");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    appDelegate.iAdView.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. If I use self.canDisplayBannerAds = true; and eliminate the other banner ads will it still call bannerViewDidLoadAd:?

Comment: @JasonBestor simply put, no. You could achieve this with some more code, but if you're going to do that you may as well implement the iAd banner as I've shown above.

Comment: @DanialStorm I ask because my app has a few other views where using self.canDisplayBannerAds = true; automatically moves up the tableviews when the ad appears and things like that. Also the banner view is disappearing when I navigate back to the main view.

Comment: @JasonBestor sounds like you need to rethink/plan the over all implementation of your iAd banners and how you want your views to react when there is an ad and when there is not an ad. I'd suggest using this code, adding a `ADBannerView` to your `storyboard` via Interface Builder, referencing the `ADBannerView` with an `outlet`, and setting constraints to the `ADBannerView` with Auto Layout.