# iAd shows white only after coming back from a certain ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, iad

I have a `tableView` with a list of `ViewControllers`. At the bottom of this tableview is an ad via iAd. When you visit any of these VCs, then hit "back" on the `navigationController`, the iAd is just as you left it--except for one of the viewcontrollers. After visiting this one, the ad is as you left it for a split second, then goes white for about ten seconds, then finally--sometimes--reloads another ad. I'm not sure what about pushing this certain VC causes the ad to fail when you go back to it. I'm thinking maybe something UI-related on the background thread, or something thread-related, but I'm not sure at all. Here is the VC's code that, after hitting "back" on the `navControl`, causes the tableView's ad to go white (this VC, another tableView, has it's own iAd and iAd delegate methods):

```
#import "RosterTableTableViewController.h"
#import "RosterListing.h"
#import "RosterListingCellTableViewCell.h"
#import "PlayerDetailViewController.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
#import "RosterListingModel.h"

@interface RosterTableTableViewController () <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    RosterListingModel *_homeModel;
    BOOL _bannerIsVisible;
    ADBannerView *_adBanner;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *rosters;
@property NSCache *imageCache;
@property UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

@end

@implementation RosterTableTableViewController

-(void)itemsDownloaded:(NSArray *)items
{
    // This delegate method will get called when the items are finished downloading

    // Set the downloaded items to the array
    _rosters = [items copy];

    [_spinner stopAnimating];

    // Reload the table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Create new HomeModel object and assign it to _homeModel variable
        _homeModel = [[RosterListingModel alloc] init];

        self.navigationItem.title = @"Roster";
        self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
        self.rosters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Set this view controller object as the delegate for the home model object
        _homeModel.delegate = self;

        // Call the download items method of the home model object
        [_homeModel downloadItems];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad");

    if (_bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        _bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear: animated];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"RosterDetail" bundle:nil];
    PlayerDetailViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayerDetailViewController"];


    // Give the PlayerViewController its key
    RosterListing *rl = [self.rosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    vc.playerNumberKey = rl.playerNumber;
    vc.playerNameKey = rl.playerName;
    vc.playerImage = rl.image;

    // Present vc
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: vc animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
                                        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    spinner.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2.0, screenHeight/5.0);
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    spinner.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    _spinner = spinner;

    // Load the Cell NIB file
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"RosterListingCellTableViewCell" bundle:nil];

    // Register this NIB, which contains the cell
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"RosterCell"];

    // Background
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ticketBackground"]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 74;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.rosters.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    RosterListingCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RosterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    RosterListing *thisRosterListing = [self.rosters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.playerNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%@",thisRosterListing.playerNumber];
    cell.playerNameLabel.text = thisRosterListing.playerName;


    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"omaha"];


    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    UIImage *playerImage = [self.imageCache objectForKey:thisRosterListing.playerImageURL];
    cell.imageView.image = playerImage;
    if (playerImage == nil) {

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig =
        [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
        thisRosterListing.playerImageURL = [thisRosterListing.playerImageURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"small" withString:@"medium"];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *imageData = [session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: thisRosterListing.playerImageURL]
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                                                    NSError *error) {
                                                    // handle NSData
                                                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                                    thisRosterListing.image = image;
                                                    [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:thisRosterListing.playerImageURL];

                                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                        cell.imageView.image = image;
                                                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                    });
                                                }];
        [imageData resume];
    }


    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicator"];
    cell.accessoryView = imageView;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // set selection color
    UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;

    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 65)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (_adBanner == nil)
    {
        _adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    }

    _adBanner.delegate = self;
    _adBanner.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [view addSubview:_adBanner];

    return view;

}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 65;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where are the rest of your `ADBannerView` [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerViewDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/ADBannerViewDelegate)? This `_adBanner.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` is not how you should be hiding your `ADBannerView`. You either need to create a [Shared Banner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) and/or [correctly implement your banner](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28708377/2108547).

Comment: The "correctly implement your banner" link does not require a shared banner? It's more or less what I was doing, no? Now I have to separate ads (iAd and a google ad) and if iAd loads, the google ad sets its alpha to 0, and if the iAd doesn't load it sets it alpha to 0 while the google ad sets its alpha to 1.

This fixes my problem in that if the iAd is white, it disappears and a google ad appears. But do I need to implement a shared ad?

Comment: If your application has only one `view` that you wish to display a `ADBannerView` on then a shared banner is **not** needed. If you have multiple `view`'s you want to display your `ADBannerView` on a shared banner is **suggested**. I actually just finished writing a shared banner in Objective-C. You can view the answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30710028/2108547).

Comment: Thank you very much. And actually, I guess I was wrong. When I return from that rosters page, the iAd is still white/blank, even with this google ad implemented. Now there's a google ad for half a second, then it gets replaced by a blank iAd.