# Working with the AppDelegate file to create a single shared iAd banner in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iad, appdelegate

I was trying to follow the steps [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html) to create a shared iAd banner for all the view controllers in my application. I couldn't understand how do I do this in the app delegate since I've never touched the app delegate before.

The instructions were:

[image]

Has anyone worked with this before?

Comment: I suggest you to search about AppDelegate explanations and iOS beginners tutorials instead of asking here. When you think you understood a little, try some approaches based on what you have learned, and after this, if you have some problem, you can finally post your code and ask what you are doing wrong etc.

Comment: Check my answers [here (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547) and [here (Obj-C)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30710028/2108547).