# UITabBar iAd Banner Not Loading Properly After Changing View

Tags: ios, iad, banner

I got a UITabBar and in each View there's a iAd Banner.
Everything works fine the first time I select a view, but when I change view and than I go back to the first one, the iAd Banner doesn't load properly (It's white and shows the iAd Logo on the right corner) and I get this error: `The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this banner`.

After about 15 seconds the Banner loads the Ad

Here's the code to load the banner (It's the same in every view)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *banner;
```

---

In viewDidLoad

```
self.banner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-29-50, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];
self.banner.delegate = (id)self;

[self.view addSubview:self.banner];
```

and

```
-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"Ad Banner action did finish");
}

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    NSLog(@"Ad Banner did load ad.");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.banner.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Unable to show ads. Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.banner.alpha = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewWillAppear` set your `ADBannerView`'s `alpha` initially to `0`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.banner.alpha = 0.0;
}
```

This way when you reload the old `view` your `ADBannerView` will be hidden until it receives an ad from the iAd network again.

A better approach would be to use a [Shared iAd Banner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30710028/2108547) across your entire application.