# Is it possible to keep an iAD showing through view controller navigation?

Tags: ios, iad

Lets say I have multiple view controllers. Say an iAD is successfully loaded on the first view controller... is it possible to retain this iAD throughout the whole app? Or do I have to attempt to load a new iAD for each view controller? Thank you.

Comment: Go through [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html) technical note. You'll get an idea about shared iAd integration.

Comment: Some starting points [Obj-C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30710028/2108547), [Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28639200/2108547).